# Dynamic property vs. fixed property query speeds on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

I'm designing datastore models and trying to decide the best approach when thinking about how the query filters are going to work.

Best if I just write out two examples. The first example is if I have a fixed "gender" property with just a string which can be set to either "male" or "female".

```
class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    gender = db.StringProperty()

p1 = Person(name="Steve", gender="male")
p2 = Person(name="Jane", gender="female")
p1.put()
p2.put()

males = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE gender = :1", "male")
```

The second example is if the Person entity is an expando model, and I dynamically set a "is_male" or "is_female" dynamic property.

```
class Person(db.Expando):
    name = db.StringProperty()

p1 = Person(name="Steve")
p1.is_male = True
p1.put()
p2 = Person(name="Jane")
p2.is_female = True
p2.put()

males = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE is_male = :1", True)
```

Now lets say that we gather millions of records and we want to do a query, which one of the two methods above would be faster in production Google App Engine running Python 2.7?

Comment: what do you mean with dynamic property? the way your second code snippet looks like there won't be anything else than name saved to the datastore so why do you think you will be able to query on that property?

Comment: Because its an expando model: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling#The_Expando_Class

Comment: the code in the question does not say that :) i suggest you update the question to reflect that 'little' detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference - models look the same in the datastore regardless of whether the property was 'dynamic' or not. The only difference is that a standard property class with no value set will insert a field with value `None` in the datastore, which takes some extra space, but allows you to query for users with that value not set.

Answer (score 2):

even if its not exactly what you are asking for i think it might give you an idea.
[Is there some performance issue between leaving empty ListProperties or using dynamic (expando) properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577301/is-there-some-performance-issue-between-leaving-empty-listproperties-or-using-dy)